# Reshaping function in numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy, pytorch, reshape

I am trying to reshape data for image classification purpose. I want to convert shape (32,32,3) to (1,3,32,32). I have used two ways for the reshaping purpose and got different results. The first one is numpy reshape method. The other code is written by me.

```
def res(t):
    n = np.zeros((3,32,32))

    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(32):
            for l in range(32):
                n[j][k][l]=t[k][l][j]

    n=n.reshape(1,3,32,32)
    return n
```

I am not able to understand what is the difference between both approaches.

Comment: Would this work? `t.T.reshape((1,) + t.T.shape)` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to do with `np.reshape` after `transpose` -

```
new = original.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(1,3,32,32)
#(32,32,3)->(3,32,32)->(1,3,32,32)

##OR##

new = original.transpose(2,0,1)[None,...]
#(32,32,3)->(3,32,32)->(1,3,32,32)
```

---

Full code with a comparison of results between your function and the transpose method.

```
t = np.random.random((32,32,3))

def res(t):
    n = np.zeros((3,32,32))

    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(32):
            for l in range(32):
                n[j,k,l]=t[k,l,j]  #<--- fixed indexing

    n=n.reshape(1,3,32,32)
    return n

## METHOD Transpose and Reshape
np.allclose(t.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(1,3,32,32), res(t))
#True

## METHOD Transpose and new axis
np.allclose(t.transpose(2,0,1)[None,...], res(t))
#True
```

Comment: `arr[][][][]` is a major anti-pattern for numpy.  It creates many intermediate arrays, which is highly inefficient.  *Always* use `arr[1, 2, 3, 4]` over `arr[1][2][3][4]`

Comment: My fix was just illustrative of the issue with OPs code with the same syntax. But you are right, I should have done both (illustrate and improve). Fixed it now.